# holomorphic and even function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is holomorphic on $D= (\ z:|z|<1)$ and $f$ is an even function 
(i.e. $f(z)=f(-z)$). Show that there is a holomorphic function $g$ on $D$ such that $g(x) = f(\sqrt{x})$ for all positive real numbers $x<1$.

I tried to let $f(z)=z^2$ and $g(z)=z$. $f(z)=f(-z)=(-z)^2=z^2$. I am stuck here.

Any ideas?

Comment: holomorphic on a disk $\implies$ analytic $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n z^n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $f$ even $\implies f'$ odd $\implies f''$ even $\implies\cdots \implies f(z) = a_0 + a_2 z^2 + a_4 z^4 + \cdots$